# What is the date format of this given date

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have the following date `2013-01-31T00:00:00-07:00` what is the date time format in this date. what `T` is for ?

Comment: T is for 'Time' and no spaces.

Comment: It's an ISO standard date/time with timezone. Surprisingly, it's very portable. And Joda time parses it without having to define a special date formatter, which is nice!

Answer (score 7):

That is [ISO 8601 Data elements and interchange formats – Information interchange – Representation of dates and times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

You can read about details in the Javadoc of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: and also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @fGo Added that, even though 1.4.2 is a little bit old.

Comment: Lutz, the doc is the same until jdk 6 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html, but they modified the doc in 7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

While @Lutz already handled the main question, for the second one: the T is merely the delimiter separating a combined date and time string.

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations):

> A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a complete
>   date expression, the letter T as a delimiter, and a valid time
>   expression. For example "2007-04-05T14:30". Either basic or extended
>   formats may be used, but both date and time must use the same format.
>   The date expression may be calendar, week, or ordinal, and must use a
>   complete representation. The time expression may use reduced accuracy.
>   It is permitted to omit the 'T' character by mutual agreement.

The T is required by standard, but optional by agreement. You should thus always specify it when interfacing with third party applications.

Answer (score -1):

The date time pattern is

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

You could find more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (examples)